# MySQL docker: Import schema file with error: inet addr:'| cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}'", "commandName": "IP"}], "clamAvInt'

Tags: mysql, docker

I am working with MySQL docker image version 5.7 with initialize the data by the schema file but got some error can't solve.
My docker command line is:

```
docker run --name mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD='abc123' -v /Users/jenkins/Desktop/irms:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d mysql:5.7
```

and get the error, the log as below:

```
$ docker run --name mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD='abc123' -v /Users/jenkins/Desktop/irms:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d mysql:5.7

2021-03-17 02:05:15+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.33-1debian10 started.
2021-03-17 02:05:15+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2021-03-17 02:05:15+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.33-1debian10 started.
2021-03-17 02:05:15+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
2021-03-17T02:05:15.606058Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2021-03-17T02:05:15.756090Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=45790
2021-03-17T02:05:15.779384Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
2021-03-17T02:05:15.837663Z 0 [Warning] No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating a new UUID: 373d4ffb-86c5-11eb-8780-0242ac110002.
2021-03-17T02:05:15.839186Z 0 [Warning] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
2021-03-17T02:05:16.450734Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2021-03-17T02:05:16.576740Z 1 [Warning] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
2021-03-17 02:05:18+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Database files initialized
2021-03-17 02:05:18+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Starting temporary server
2021-03-17 02:05:18+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Waiting for server startup
2021-03-17T02:05:18.819727Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2021-03-17T02:05:18.820623Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.33) starting as process 78 ...
2021-03-17T02:05:18.822725Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2021-03-17T02:05:18.822772Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2021-03-17T02:05:18.822783Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-03-17T02:05:18.822789Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2021-03-17T02:05:18.822795Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-03-17T02:05:18.822800Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2021-03-17T02:05:18.823072Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-03-17T02:05:18.823301Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2021-03-17T02:05:18.824551Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2021-03-17T02:05:18.829149Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-03-17T02:05:18.830692Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2021-03-17T02:05:18.841912Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2021-03-17T02:05:18.846985Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2021-03-17T02:05:18.847098Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2021-03-17T02:05:18.862891Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2021-03-17T02:05:18.863475Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2021-03-17T02:05:18.863521Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2021-03-17T02:05:18.863960Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2021-03-17T02:05:18.914486Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.33 started; log sequence number 2746831
2021-03-17T02:05:18.915203Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2021-03-17T02:05:18.915523Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2021-03-17T02:05:18.916967Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 210317  2:05:18
2021-03-17T02:05:18.920098Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
2021-03-17T02:05:18.920168Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of SSL certificates as certificate files are present in data directory.
2021-03-17T02:05:18.920570Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2021-03-17T02:05:18.920635Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of RSA key pair as key files are present in data directory.
2021-03-17T02:05:18.922497Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2021-03-17T02:05:18.926990Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2021-03-17T02:05:18.927219Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.33'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2021-03-17 02:05:19+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server started.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone1970.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.

2021-03-17 02:05:20+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/IRMSDB_2021-03-09.sql
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 287: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'inet addr:'| cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}'", "commandName": "IP"}], "clamAvInt' at line 5
```

I checked my schema file and no idea what the error exactly and no idea how to fix it.

My schema file is exported from Sequel Pro.

Could you kindly provide some idea to solve the problem?
Thanks very much.

Just attached my schema file below, and please change the extension name from jpg to SQL.

[Click here to download: MySQL schema file](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/6060224/110509044-a6b78d00-813c-11eb-8b9b-129679034cd1.jpg)

Comment: The fragment from the error message sounds like Bourne shell syntax, not SQL.  Can you edit the question to include the actual text of the SQL schema (not a link and not an image), at least enough of it to demonstrate the error?

Comment: The schema file includes the database data and is large, more than 20000 lines, so I provide the link

Comment: @DavidMaze, just appended the docker log, the error I think is comes from "/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh" and this shell script is built-in MySQL docker, and it is executing in docker building layer?

Comment: @DavidMaze, the schema file will create the database schema, and also will insert the sample data, so the schema file is large, it's the reason I provide the link instead of pasting the schema lines in the question.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] for the question to be meaningful.  That means trimming down the input to the minimum necessary to demonstrate the issue.  The error message mentions line 287 of the file, for example; what's on that single specific line?